# Rails Devise edit registration without password confirmation except for changing password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, forms-authentication

By default devise requires a current password confirmation in order to change user details.

By adding this code to my registration controller I can make it such this confirmation password is not needed:

```
  protected 

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end
```

However, what I need is to change any information about profile (name, email, telephone etc.) without current password confirmation.

At the same time, in order to set a new password the old password should be required.

As you can see I have no current / old password columns:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150311113109) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string   "first_name",                          null: false
    t.string   "last_name",                           null: false
    t.string   "telephone",                           null: false
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.text     "address"
    t.integer  "admin",                  default: 0,  null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a validation with a proc like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :current_password, on: :update, :if => proc { |user| user.password.present? }
 end
```

Comment: @VladOtrocol You have a password, and a current_password fields.